# Threaded comment system in PHP for image blog

Tags: php, mysql

I own an image blog (similar to 9gag) and I want to set up a threaded comment system. I understood the way to go is to have a closure table, so I build one.

My question is: what is the SQL query to get the comment tree in order (and avoiding nested SELECT query which have an impact on perf) ?

Comments Table:

```
image_id
comment_id
comment_text
comment_date
comment_parent_id
```

Comments_tree Table:

```
ancestor
descendant
depth
image_id
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think he table is not correctly normalized I think you should use the comment_id as primary key.

And to your Question ist not the query thats hard ist the PHP to print the tree.

You can just select everything where comment_parent_id is null:

```
SELECT comment_text FROM comments_table WHERE comment_parent_id IS NULL ORDER BY comment_date DESC;
```

Ist now sorted by Name and for the next query just use the id of the parent comment:

```
SELECT comment_text FROM comments_table WHERE comment_parent_id = $parentCommentId ORDER BY comment_date DESC;
```

You can use the PHP variable `$parentCommentId` to save the ID of the parent comment.

After all of that you just have to output it correctly!